# How does NextJS detects & fetches a new page?

Tags: webpack, next.js, webpack-dev-server, webpack-plugin

In a fresh NextJS project, I start the dev server by running `yarn dev` and add the following code to the `pages/index.jsx`:

```
export default Home(){
 return <Link href="/abc">Go to abc</Link>
}
```

Suppose I create a new page in the `pages` directory called `abc.js` with the following code:

```
export default AbcPage(){
 return <div>Welcome to ABC page.</div>
}
```

By looking at the output in the terminal, it seems the new page has not been compiled yet, and the moment I click on the `abc` in the home page, compilation happens and a `abc.js` chunk is downloaded in the browser.

**My question is, how did NestJS configure webpack to load chunks on-demand?**

Some relevant files I looked into are:

- `packages/next/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.ts`
- `packages/next/client/index.tsx`
- `packages/next/client/page-loader.ts`
- `packages/next/build/webpack/plugins/flight-client-entry-plugin.ts`

It seems the last one in the above list holds the key to my question. I also `https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1422`.

Comment: I guess there will be some relevance with the `<Link/>` component too. Can you also look in **Next Link** component code.

Comment: It seems that it has a `PageLoader` that has a `routeLoader` property. The `RouteLoder` has a method called `getFilesForRoute` that calls another method `appendScript`. I think the crux is in how the Webpack has been configured (maybe dynamic entry that can produce iife output).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the same in the future, I have finally cracked what's going under the hood and trying to compile it [here](https://github.com/cruxcode/til/blob/main/next.js/development-mode.md).